# How to check if a array of resource names were already declared in puppet

Tags: arrays, puppet

I've an array of ip addresses with ports like

```
$addr_port = ['1.2.3.4:88','3.4.5.6:8080']
```

In the manifest I've do do something with each combination of ip address and port (only once per combination per host). Therefore I've a defined type:

```
::do_something_with_each_element {$addr_port:}
```

But it is possible that the same combination of ip address and port could be defined several times so it would be a duplicate declaration.

Normally it is possible to prevent the duplicate declaration with something like that:

```
$resource_name = 'my_resource'
if ! defined(Do_something_with_each_element[$resource_name]) {
   ::do_something_with_each_element {$resource_name:}
}
```

But if `$resource_name` is an array like `$addr_port` we get a invalid argument error in the `defined` function.

A second approach would be to use the .each method for arrays. Unfortunately that solution needs the future parser of puppet which isn't an available requirement.

The third idea is to use a custom function instead of a defined type. That would work but is would be nasty since a custom function has to be unique over the complete environment.

Is there any other possible solution?

Comment: Have you tried virtual resources? https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/virtual_resources.html

Comment: I used `ensure_resource()` from the puppetlabs stdlib (>= 2.5.x). It works. @PeterSouter I am not sure how you would do that with virtual resources. Could you make an example for other people that maybe run into this problem?

Comment: ensure_resource is a little hacky, but it would work for you. I'll see if I can make an example of the virtual resource for you also :)